# Como puedo filtrar un pipe en angular pero según categoría

Tags: javascript, array, angular, filtro, pipe

Tengo este simple código en un pipe , pero siempre me devuelve no solamente el elemento filtrado de esa categoria sino los demás elementos que hay de otras categorias, como haría para que solo se vea ese elemento o los elementos de esta categoría, o también para que no se muestren los demás elementos.

**TS**

```
 constructor(
    public _category: categoriesService, 
  ) { }
     transform(items: Array<Products>): Array<any> { 
      return items.filter(item => item.idCategory == this._category.id);
    }  
    return items
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of (products | filterProducts)">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu pipe deber recibir como argumento la lista de items y la categoria a filtrar algo asi

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filterProducts'
})
export class FilterProductsPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(items: Array<Product>, categoryToSearch: string = ''): Array<any> {
        // si la categoria a buscar es vacia, null o undefined retornamos todos los items sin filtar nada
        if (!categoryToSearch) {
            return items;
        }
        
        // aqui asumó que tu interfaz de producto tiene una propiedad llamada category por la cual vamos a filtrar
        return items.filter(({ category }) => category === categoryToSearch);
    }
}
```

y en tu html

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of (products | filterProducts: category)">
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, pero sigue igual, nose se si tendras algun ejemplo echo.

Comment: Tambien quiero aclarar que no es busqueda sino que al picar en una categoria directamente tendria que salir esos productos , osea tengo para elegir frutas , y me sale pera , manzana y limon, pero como limon es tipo citrico quiero q solo filtre los citricos algo asi